# Gnome-mount alternative in Ubuntu 10.04 or how to mount partition with normal user rights

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-10.04, automount

i was using gnome-mount to automount drives but in lucid it was removed.
So is there any alternatives in lucid except editing fstab and programs that do so?

Gnome-mount is a program which mounts disks using the same facilities as when mounting a disk as a normal user through Nautilus. There is no need to setup mountpoints or filesystems. This is particularly interesting if you want to use the automatically created mountpoints instead of manually specifying them for each disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there is no `gnome-mount` there should still be `gvfs-mount`

```
$ gvfs-mount --help
Usage:
  gvfs-mount [OPTION...] - mount <location>

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options

Application Options:
  -m, --mountable          Mount as mountable
  -d, --device             Mount volume with device file
  -u, --unmount            Unmount
  -s, --unmount-scheme     Unmount all mounts with the given scheme
  -l, --list               List
  -i, --detail             Show extra information for List and Monitor
  -o, --monitor            Monitor events
```

And as for the need to set up mountpoints manually via `/etc/fstab`, are you sure you didn't do something to break the functionality that came with gnome? This shouldn't require manual intervention.

Comment: Well i think you misunderstood me. I dont want to edit fstab and set mount points. Because i if do so mounting/unmounting from nautilus will not work correct. 
In 9.10 i was able to add "gnome-mount -p Data" to startup applications and everything was perfect.

Comment: Well thank you for solution i tried with gvfs-mount and looks like everything is working in spite of these errors:
<pre>
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1

(gvfs-mount:17543): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_mount_get_root:assertion `G_IS_MOUNT (mount)' failed

(gvfs-mount:17543): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_file_get_path:assertion`G_IS_FILE (file)' failed

Mounted /dev/sdb1 at (null)

(gvfs-mount:17543): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref:assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gvfs-mount:17543): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref:assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

<code>

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 10.04, referring to methods described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions):

> Four methods will be discussed:
>
> 1. The first method is manually editing Ubuntu's filesystem table. This
>      sounds more complex than it really is.
> 2. The second method, specific to
>      Dapper, is described at MountingWindowsPartitions.
> 3. The third - simple - method is to install the pysdm package (in Gutsy) and then use
>      System-Administration-Storage Device Manager without any manual
>      editing of the fstab file, and disregard most of the instructions that
>      follow.
> 4. The fourth and last method does not rely on modifying Ubuntu's
>      filesystem table. Instead, it uses the automatic facilities present in
>      Gnome. Disks are mounted just like a regular user would do (only
>      available in Hardy and Karmic).

1. Is more complex than is advertised. Later on it turns out that the described method includes risks.
2. Specific to Dapper as mentioned - outdated.
3. Pysdm does not work right now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pysdm/+bug/559416
4. "uses the automatic facilities present in Gnome" which was the method this thread already mentioned in the first place; not working.

So, there are four methods, but still no solution for automounting a partition in 2011.