# In Linux how do I mount a OS-X partition * by name * that is on the same host?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, gnome, mount

I once used gnome-mount like this

```
gnome-mount -o ro -d /dev/sda2 or gnome-mount -o ro -p "Macintosh HD"
```

But, alas, gnome-mount seems to be no more. RIP.

I can do this

```
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sda2
```

(which generates a whole lot of errors but does mount the partition in the /media directory.)

This is a related question: [Gnome-mount alternative in Ubuntu 10.04 or how to mount partition with normal user rights](https://superuser.com/questions/131918/gnome-mount-alternative-in-ubuntu-10-04-or-how-to-mount-partition-with-normal-use)

But how do you do it by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gvfs-mount` doesn't seem to have that option.
http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/gvfs-mount/

Normal `mount` should be able to do this however.

```
mount -o ro -L "Macintosh HD" /mountpoint
```

`mount` requires you to create the mountpoints first though.

Comment: That will do what I want. Thanks - I feel silly that I didn't think of `mount`.

Comment: I can always mkdir /mnt/Macintosh\ HD before I mount it so that is not really a problem.